# Not to change calendar color of UIDatePicker when the isEnabled is false

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying not to change the color of calendar of UIDatePicker when the `isEnabled` is false.

```swift
import UIKit

class DatePicker: UIDatePicker {
    
    override open var isEnabled: Bool {
        didSet {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if !self.isEnabled {
                    self.tintColor = Colors.accent
                    self.alpha = 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I made a subclass of UIDatePicker, `DatePicker` for tryout. Then I turned `isEnabled` to false in my another swift code.

```swift
@IBOutlet weak var calendar: DatePicker!
calendar.isEnabled = false
```

Is it possible to keep the original color of UIDatePicker even if it is disabled?

Comment: Do you want to change the text colour of the view of picker ?

Comment: You could set `.isUserInteractionEnabled = false` instead... this won't change the visual appearance.